# Где посмотреть старые спутниковые снимки местности?

Tags: api, карты

Возможно найду ответ на свой вопрос здесь, если кто то подскажет. Есть сервисы google maps и подобные. Там отображаются достаточно современные снимки местности, где можно посмотреть и есть ли такая возможность на снимки до 2000 и ранее годов?

up

снизу ссылка на https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/, как им пользоваться? на примере города Бобруйск 1995гг

up

возможно есть другие сервисы?

Comment: вроде в Google Earth Pro можно просматривать

Comment: https://earthengine.google.com/timelapse/#v=34.34547,16.55432,0,latLng&t=0.00 из демки можно надергать тайлов

Answer (score 0):

Скачиваем https://www.google.com/intl/ru/earth/about/versions/#download-pro . В меню поиска можно набрать нужный вам город , на верхний панели есть кнопка часы с зелёной стрелочкой , нажимайте. Появится меню перемотки , либо используйте стрелочки по бокам чтобы перемещаться по снимкам в хронологическом порядке.

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: расскажите как им пользоваться, допустим хочу посмотреть на город Бобруйск образца 1995 года

Comment: Я изменил ответ , Бобруйск с +- адекватным разрешением доступен с 2004 года , есть и 1985 , но этот снимок ужасен(нельзя приблизить даже так чтобы увидеть дома )

Comment: что тогда https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/ это? как пользоваться? про google earth я знаю, но там не достаточно далеко во времени можно переместиться

Comment: @usert  а это другой сервис, со своим набором снимков.

Comment: @eri, как в нем посмотреть бобруйск 1995?

Comment: Слева в верху видишь кнопку поиск? Вводишь там Бобруйск и нажимаешь "поиск"

Comment: В 1995 году были спутники?

Comment: Напишешь сюда если не понятно что делать дальше

Comment: @eri конечно Вики, но "Первая спутниковая фотография Земли была сделана 14 августа 1959 года американским спутником Explorer 6"

Comment: @FGC нет, не вижу там поиск

Comment: *1984 , ">Поиск " в верхнем левом углу. Нажимаете на него он разворачивается

Comment: Вы же скачали , а не используете электронную версию?

Comment: @FGC, я у вас спросил про сервис  https://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/, не вижу там поиска

Comment: он отвечает за свой ответ, а не за ваш) добавьте ответ и обсуждайте его отдельно

Comment: на  earthexplorer.usgs.gov нужна учетная запись